# Azure webrole naming

Tags: naming-conventions, azure, cloud

What is a good naming conventention for web role-, worker role- (and vm role) projects in Visual Studio( 2010) ?

(edit):

And what about the deploy ? The name of the web role will affect your deployed app named in the Cloud....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it matters a lot. Number of roles in the project is usually very small.  Oftentimes, the web and vm roles maybe user-visible via URL's, (blahblah.cloudapp.net). So I would name them by functionality and ease of reading and not prefix them or post-fix them with a special "worker", or "web", or "vm" keywords, as you are probably thinking.

Comment: Hi Igorek, accepted! The name DOES matter as the name is part of the public URL. So I agree with you to not postfix with a role type, but only with a functional name.

Answer (score 0):

Its entirely arbiratry(sp). And unless you're adding a degree of automated monitoring and management doesn't have any significant impact.

My personal preferrence is to name them appropriately based on the unit of work, following whatever naming convention is appropriate for your shop.

The bigger question is the management of services and subscriptions, which gets a bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suffix them with ".Web" or ".Worker". Visual Studio does something similar with Silverlight projects, if you let VS generate your Silverlight host app.